# Matlab: delete complete line in txt-file if there is a non-ascii-character

Tags: matlab

I'm currently writing a Matlab code to plot measurement data. Unfortunately there is a hardware problem with serial communication and sometimes i receive just gibberish. My code works only for defined data, so this gibberish has to be removed. I want something like this pseudo code:

```
for eachLine
   if currentLineContainsNonASCII
      delete completeLine
   end if
end for
```

the data is read like this

```
rawdataInputFilename = 'measurementData.txt';  
fileID = fopen(rawdataInputFilename);

% load data as string 
DataCell = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s','HeaderLines', 1);
```

I was thinking about first creating a new 'clean' file with only ASCII chars and then reading that file with my actual plotting code.

Where I stuck is how to identify a non ASCII and then deleting the whole line, not only overwriting that single char.

Some example data, 1. and 3. line are 'clean' and can be handled with the current code. Second Line has non ASCIIs in it and therefore kills my code. Whitespace characters are windows linefeed, tab and space.

```
61 380 Module03 Slot02 27.01.2015 13:47:13  450 3587 1175 84    101.83 22.30 5.20 1  1
62 386 Module03 Slot03 27.01.2015 13:47:18  450ÆăǳШШ    106.83 22.30 25.20 1    1 
63 391 Module03 Slot04 27.01.2015 13:47:24  ERROR dgsf 5643332  103.26 22.40 25.20 1 1
```

Comment: What is your question? How to identify non-ASCII chars? Or how to delete the line? For the later please put some example code how the reading looks like into your question.

Comment: Can you paste in an example of the data you're getting?

Comment: Read about [fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to read line by line. Check the line with [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) and write it to another file if it passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the received character is in the range [32, 127], otherwise skip it.

The following function will tell you if there is any non-printable character in a given string:

```
function R = has_non_printable_characters(str)
    % Remove non-printable characters
    str2 = str(31<str & str<127); 
    % check if length of resulting string is the same than input string
    R = (lenght(str) > length(str2))
end;
```

If instead of just skipping the entire string you want to remove non-printable characters keeping the printable ones, modify the function and return `str2`. (And change the function name so it matches the new behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.

Save that to a text file named `data.txt`:

```
bla Header bla
61 380 Module03 Slot02 27.01.2015 13:47:13  450 3587 1175 84    101.83 22.30 5.20 1  1
62 386 Module03 Slot03 27.01.2015 13:47:18  450ÆăǳШШ    106.83 22.30 25.20 1    1 
63 391 Module03 Slot04 27.01.2015 13:47:24  ERROR dgsf 5643332  103.26 22.40 25.20 1 1
```

### Method 1 (using textscan and cellfun):

Removing the non-ASCII line completely:

```
fileID = fopen('data.txt');    % open file
DataCell = textscan(fileID,'%s','delimiter','','HeaderLines', 1);    % read a complete line of text, ignore the first line
fclose(fileID);    % close file
DataCell = DataCell{1};    % there is only one string per line
DataCell(cellfun(@(x) any(x>127),DataCell)) = [];    % remove line if there is any non-ASCII in it, adjust that to your liking, i.e (x>126 | x<32)

celldisp(DataCell)
```

> DataCell{1} =
>
> 61 380 Module03 Slot02 27.01.2015 13:47:13  450 3587 1175 84    101.83 22.30 5.20 1  1
>
> DataCell{2} =
>
> 63 391 Module03 Slot04 27.01.2015 13:47:24  ERROR dgsf 5643332  103.26 22.40 25.20 1 1

You could now loop over the cell array or, if you like, start all over again with the updated text (f.e. as input to `textscan`). To do that join the cells together to one big chunk of text:

```
strjoin(DataCell','\n')
```

> ans =
>
> 61 380 Module03 Slot02 27.01.2015 13:47:13  450 3587 1175 84    101.83 22.30 5.20 1  1
>   63 391 Module03 Slot04 27.01.2015 13:47:24  ERROR dgsf 5643332  103.26 22.40 25.20 1 1

### Method 2 (using regexprep):

I'm loading the whole text file at once and replacing any line with an empty string `''`, which does not contain a given set of characters.

```
s = fileread('data.txt');
snew = regexprep(s, '.*[^\w\s.:].*\n', '', 'dotexceptnewline')
```

> snew =
>
> 61 380 Module03 Slot02 27.01.2015 13:47:13  450 3587 1175 84    101.83 22.30 5.20 1  1
>
> 63 391 Module03 Slot04 27.01.2015 13:47:24  ERROR dgsf 5643332  103.26 22.40 25.20 1 1

The `[^\w\s.:]` bit bascially translates to:
Match any chararcter which is not (the `^` means not):

- alphabetic, numeric or underscore (`\w`)
- whitespace (`\s`)
- a dot `.` or
- a colon `:`

If you want to exclude any other ASCII character, just add it (to within the brackets).

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which creates a new txt-file whitout the lines with non-ASCII

```
%% read in via GUI
[inputFilename, inputPathname] = uigetfile('*.txt', ...
    'Pick a .txt file from which you want to remove lines with non ASCII characters.');
if isequal(inputFilename, 0)
    disp('User selected ''Cancel''')
else
    disp(['User selected ', fullfile(inputPathname, inputFilename)])
    inputFileID = fopen(fullfile(inputPathname, inputFilename)); %open/load file
end

tempCell = (strsplit(inputFilename,'.'));
inputFilenameWOextension = cell2mat(tempCell(1));
fileExtension = cell2mat(tempCell(2));

outputFileID = fopen([inputFilenameWOextension, '_ASCIIonly.', fileExtension], 'w'); %overwrite existing file

% get a single line of text
tline = fgetl(inputFileID);
while tline ~= -1
    % get a single line of text
    tline = fgetl(inputFileID);

    % Remove non-printable characters
    tempStr = tline(tline<127); % not really ASCII, but also tab
    %tempStr = tline(31<tline & tline<127); % true ASCII
    if (length(tempStr) < length(tline));
       continue; 
    else
        fprintf(outputFileID, '%s\r\n', tempStr);
    end

end
fclose(inputFileID);
fclose(outputFileID);
```